# Centering three links so they are equally spaced across the page

Tags: html, css

My professor gave the class an image that may be similar to something he may ask us to replicate on an upcoming exam. His suggestion was to go home and see if we can make a clone to study. I have the most of it down but he has these three links at the top that are PERFECTLY distributed across the page.

I have played with numbers for hours. I have gotten close but its not quite replicating the image. I have tried making the width of the links 33% and the margins 1.66% but I actually got some unexpected results where the browser puts one of the links below the other. It only confuses me more if were being honest. His image is so perfect to me it hints at some math and not just fiddling with numbers until it works.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="practiceTest.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="box1">
        <a href="https://www.google.com" id="googLink">Google</a>
        <a href="https://www.microsoft.com" id="microLink">Microsoft</a>
        <a href="https://www.yahoo.com" id="yahooLink">Yahoo</a>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div id="box2">
        <h1 id="header">Guest Book</h1>

        <form action="post">
            First Name:
            <input type="text" id="fistName">
            Last Name: 
            <input type="text" id="lastName">
            College:
            <input type="checkbox" name="Business" id="business">
            Business
            <input type="checkbox" name="Education" id="education">
            Education
            <input type="checkbox" name="arts" id="arts">
            <br>
            Current Profession:
            <select>
                <option value="idk">unemployed</option>
                <option value="idk1">idk1</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            Comments:
            <br>
            <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="2"></textarea>
            Would you like to share your comments with others?
            <br>
            <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes">
            <input type="radio" name="yes" id="yes">
            <hr>
            <button type="submit">Send</button>
            <button type="reset">Clear</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <div id="box3">
        Copyright - Made up Name
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
#box1{
    background-color: black;
    align-self: center;
    padding: 20px;

}

a{
    align-content: center;
    width: 20%;
    margin:0 5.33%;
    padding: 10px 0;
    color: azure;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration-line: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;

}

body{
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}

#box2{
    padding: 20px 20px;
    margin: auto 10px;
    background-color: white;
    color: darkred;
}

#box3{
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: have you tried using `display: flex` and `justify-content: between`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using margin of 1.66% from left/right sides then reduce the same from your width i.e. **33.33% - 1.66% - 1.66%**. Hence, your width shall be **30.01%** in the case. Please ensure that you're using `float:left` because `display:inline-block` takes extra space around the element.

If you also want to add some padding within the `a` tags then you also need to use `box-sizing:border-box` to make the padding count within the scope of element's width.

***New Suggestion:***

As an alternate, you may also use `display:flex` as well and distribute the spacing equally. You may easily find resources on Google about how to use `display:flex` (or say *css flexbox layout model*).